# Map layers get stretched

Tags: openlayers

I am newbee for the Openlayer and my site is using openlayer 2.2.13. Basically, exactly I would like to do is

1. Base layer as blank canvas
2. Over one kml layer[typical map layer]
3. Highlight the area for a user on map.

I have implemented this functionality but the one issue which as follows,

=> I am using lat/long information for drawing map. All the tree layers of map get generated but map is stretched. I have tried many ways to set projects, displayprojections, sphericalMercator but still isuee continues.

[Please review reference map screenshot from here](https://drive.google.com/a/clariontechnologies.co.in/file/d/0B4xPnUHokwtZNkNVRmNEc3E3QjA/view)

Comment: Hi Ankit. Have you tried you data in another kind of viewer? In other word: Do you know that the problem is not in your data.

Comment: Hi Anders, Thanks for your reply. But, can you please elaborate in more detail by "another kind of viewer"?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".